# How add AIR project in Crashlytics dashboard?

Tags: actionscript-3, air-native-extension, crashlytics

I include in my AIR Mobile project [Air Native Extension for Crashlytics from freshplanet](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Crashlytics). I build my application to *.apk file. How can I add my AIR project in Crashlytics dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far it seems only to be possible to add a project to the dashboard via the crashlytics IDE plugin.

The problem is that I don't have an android module so the plugin is not enabling me to create a new app to use in the dashboard